# Add Spring Sleuth to Spring Oauth2's requests

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2, spring-cloud-sleuth

We have problem with propagation of `traceId` in requests which are called by spring oauth2 module.

For instance consider authorization and resource server. In resource server we have spring security configuration to ensure get rsa public key from authorization server with following property:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      jwk:
        key-set-uri: http://authorization-server:8080/key-set
```

When I call controller of resource server with jwt token, I can see in zipkin traces from resource server and authorization server as well, but there is no traceId propagation from resource server to authorization server.

[image]

First record is calling rest api to get resources, and second record is produced call to authorization server to find out public RSA key.